# Ionic 2 placeholder text styling

Tags: html, css, angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

I am working on an application using Ionic 2 rc0 and have several input fields throughout the application that still need styling.

```
<ion-item class="su-p3-item">
  <ion-label floating class="su-input">Your name</ion-label>
  <ion-input type="text" class="su-input"></ion-input>
</ion-item>
```

ionic 2 input api http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/components/input/Input/

Specifically, I need to change the styling of the placeholder text, and bottom-border when active. Through the API, and provided SASS variable overrides, i could not figure out how to override the inherited styles for borders and placeholder text for input fields.

I would like to avoid using '!important' in addition to these changes on affecting the specific page each input is on (I dont want the changes to be 'global').

Answer (score 27, accepted):

With Ionic2 RC4, you have to add the following line in your app.scss file:

```
.text-input::-moz-placeholder {
  color: white;
}

.text-input:-ms-input-placeholder {
  color: white;
}

.text-input::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  text-indent: 0;
  color: white;
}
```

Comment: it does work, in my case my input is an `ion-searchbar` component so I had to: `.searchbar-md .searchbar-input::-webkit-input-placeholder { color: yellow }`

Answer (score 10):

Just do the ::placeholder selector, i.e.

```
<ion-input placeholder="enter placeholder here..." class="custom-input" type="text"></ion-input>
```

and in css just call it like

```
ion-input {
  &.custom-input {
    font-size: 20px; //sets text font size
    ::placeholder {
      font-size: 12px; //sets placeholder font size
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Good option for page specific styling compared to other answers

Comment: thanks this doesnt work for ion-select ion ionic5 though

Answer (score 5):

Ionic 2 provides [sass variable overrides](https://ionicframework.com/docs/theming/overriding-ionic-variables/) you can use to easily change the style.

theme/variables.scss

```
$text-input-placeholder-color:(#000);
```

Answer (score 5):

This works for me :D

```
ionic cli 4.1.1
```

example.scss

```
ion-input {
    ::placeholder{
        color:white !important;
    }
}
```

example.html

```
<ion-input placeholder="Username" type="text"></ion-input>
```

Answer (score 1):

For Ionic 4 from docs [custom-properties](https://beta.ionicframework.com/docs/api/input/#css-custom-properties).

```
<ion-input class="custom-class"></ion-input>
```

`*.scss`

```
ion-input {
    &.custom-class {
        --placeholder-color: #fff;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For Ionic2.0 , inside file app.ms.css I tried to do styling over *.text-input::-moz-placeholder* around line number 6069 and it worked. Same can be tried for RC0

Answer (score 0):

In case someone needs help:

```
ion-input {
            color: #000000ad !important;
            font-size: 16pt;
            --placeholder-color: black !important;
            --placeholder-opacity: 100%;
          }
```

opacity value makes it looks like just like input text.