# Ionic 4: Style input placeholder

Tags: css, ionic-framework, sass, ionic4

I'm trying to style the placeholder of my Ionic 4 application.The HTML looks as follows:

```
<form>
  <ion-grid>
    <ion-row class='label'>Name</ion-row>
    <ion-row>
      <ion-item>
        <ion-input type='text' [(ngModel)]='recipe.name' name='name' placeholder='Name'></ion-input>
      </ion-item>
    </ion-row>
    <ion-row class='label'>Weight</ion-row>
    <ion-row>
      <ion-item>
        <ion-input type='number' [(ngModel)]='recipe.weight' name='weight' placeholder='Weight'></ion-input>
        <ion-label>kg</ion-label>
      </ion-item>
    </ion-row>
  </ion-grid>
</form>
```

If tried out [Ionic 2.x solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40091138/ionic-2-placeholder-text-styling) yet it did not work out.

I've figured out that if you set a color in *ion-item* it styles the entire text of the input field

```
ion-item {
    ion-input{
        color:red;
    }
}
```

when using the pseudo class *:placeholder-shown* or the pseudo element *::placeholder* on *ion-input* though the styling shows no effect.

What am I doing wrong? Is there even a possibility in Ionic 4 to style input placeholder ?

**Edit:**

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular6-with-ionic4-list-refresh-test) to fork with Ionic 4 and Angular 6

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Use this style code:

```
ion-input{
    --placeholder-color: red;
    --placeholder-opacity: 1;
}
```

See here:https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular6-with-ionic4-list-refresh-test-yq3ntj?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: tell me for more help ::)

Comment: you can remove important from your example and it still works

Comment: happy to help :) (I found solution by see in F12)

Answer (score 1):

Please try this general styling to see if it has any effect:

```
::-webkit-input-placeholder { /* Chrome/Opera/Safari */
  color: red;
}
::-moz-placeholder { /* Firefox 19+ */
  color: red;
}
:-ms-input-placeholder { /* IE 10+ */
  color: red;
}
:-moz-placeholder { /* Firefox 18- */
  color: red;
}
```

Comment: It showed no effect. Still black text and grey-ish placeholder

Comment: can you try using !important on the example shown above, just for testing purposes/

Comment: It works perfect use `!important`:https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-x8d8vy?file=pages/home/home.html

Comment: Yes, but if you use it like that it will affect the entire website, if you want something more specific, you can target the desired class and put at the end the pseudo elements. Cheers!

Comment: I added an _!important_ behind every red. Yet still no success

Comment: can you provide us the css code behind your project, or even better, a codepen or jsfiddle to see exactly what is going on there. The html alone is not helping us very much

Comment: @לבנימלכה the problem is, that your stackblitz is ionic 3 while my project is running on ionic 4

Comment: Yes I know I can not find stackblitz with version 4 but I think it the same

Comment: @TorjescuSergiu there is no futher css in the procet except the default  import of ~@ionic imports in the gobal.scss

Comment: @לבנימלכה if added a stackblitz to the bottom of my question

Comment: @MirJo I copied code to stackblitz and it does not work:https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular6-with-ionic4-list-refresh-test-yq3ntj?file=src/app/app.component.html

Comment: the 
<ion-content padding> on top and bottom needs to be removed, then it works

Comment: I cannot find the form provided in the question in the stackblitz example

Comment: @MirJo see my answer

Answer (score 1):

Some components, like datetime, use your own html structure.
So I has apply more tags to changed all inputs.

```
ion-datetime {
  --placeholder-color: rgba(211, 211, 211, 0.4);
}

ion-input, ion-textarea, ion-select {
  --placeholder-color: rgba(211, 211, 211, 1);
}
```

I don't understand why I use different alpha values... but it worked!

[image]